# Calculate throughput every second in UDP client server in C

Tags: c, sockets

I need to calculate throughput of a UDP connection between a client and a server in `C`, catch is, I need to do this *every second* and plot a graph regarding this. I'm looking for ideas regarding how should I do this, given I am sending the packets at a fixed interval in `C` ?

My client side code is like this :

```
for(int i = 0;i < num_messages;i++){

  int bytes_sent = sendto(socket_id, &rtt_struct, sizeof(rtt_struct), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, addr_size);

  int bytes_rcvd = recvfrom(socket_id, &new_rtt_struct, sizeof(new_rtt_struct), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, &addr_size);

  sleep(interval);

}
```

where, `num_messages` is the number of packets I send to the server.

Comment: All you need to do is measure the time around your send/receive calls and then divide bytes by time.

Comment: Yes, but how to do this every _second_ and record it somewhere ? @JonathonReinhart

Comment: @Jarvis: I have an idea. Have four counters. (1) Number of bytes sent (2) Received (3)Time taken for sending bytes as measured across sendto (4) Across recvfrom. Inside for loop, get system time. Every second calculate throughput from the counters and reset them.

Comment: The question is how to do every second ? @MayurK

Comment: @Jarvis: Create a thread. Let that thread sleep for one second and then read the counter values and calculate throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose the following approach:

- Use a wrapper for the lowlevel send- and receive functions, which updates a global counter for sent and received bytes.
- Install a signal handler for `SIGALRM`, which is called once a second (`alarm(1);`). You can use `sigaction(2)` to eliminate the need to reinstall it with every call, but you will have to place a call to `alarm()` inside the signal handler to restart the timer.
- Each time the signal handler is called, read and reset the global counters and handle the byte count (i.e. write it into a data structure which is later used to generate the graphs)

For creating the graphs I can warmly suggest rrdtool/librrd.

Comment: To get even more precise numbers (in case the timer / alarm fires a bit late, or all cores are very busy), instead of one global counter a small array (say 1024 items) could be used to store and update the numbers (at index `(currenttime - basetime) & 0x03FF` - times in seconds). This would also allow for the timer to be fired at longer intervals if acceptable. Only drawback would be the call to time() (or some other timing function) at each send/receive (not sure how expensive that call is).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what your sleep interval is at all so it is hard to know what you need. If interval is higher than one second, then reduce it to 1 second, perform your statistics and then sleep the remainder.  If your sleep interval is less than a second, then you just need to keep track of how long you've slept in total.

You do this by calling time() or gettimeofday() , before you start your loop, and saved the current time.

Then after each sleep()   find the current time and compare it to the last time. If it is greater than one second difference then print your statistics, zero your counter,  save the time again and then continue

Pseudo code:

```
time_t last time = time()
long sent_counter= 0
for() // your same  loop from before
     //your send, as before
     //your receive, as before
      time_t now = time()
      sent_counter += bytes_sent;

      sleep()

      if(now - last_time > 1)
          Printf (...); // print the counter 
          counter = 0;
          last_time = now;
```

If you don't need it to be really accurate (like just printing progress) you can just use time() like this,  but if you need accurate statistics then you'll need to use gettimeofday() instead so that you can get times with microseconds too